# What is the significance of personality & power level?

Tags: neko-atsume

In Neko Atsume, each cat has a personality and power level statistic, which appear to be revealed when you take a picture of them. Does either of these stats have an effect in game?

Answer (score 3):

Power level is used to determine if a cat can use a toy or occupy a space while another cat is currently there. For example, if a cat with a power level of 50 is using a ball of yarn, and another cat with a power level of 75 decided to use the same item, the second cat can push the first out because of the higher power level.

The personalities may hint at what types of items a cat will interact with.

Source: http://nekoatsume.wikia.com/wiki/Catbook

Answer (score 1):

Personality affects with what cats do usually play with. (e.g. a Mellow cat usually plays with balls, a Laid Back cat usually stays in bags)

I think that the Power Level affects gift sizes and quality, so a high-powered cat may bring you more fish than a low-powered one.